# Selecting fields using variables for the fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a dropdown list where the user can select the fields they wish to have displayed. I can create a variable, say $field_list which then has 3 (user selected) fields, say title, first_name,last_name. So my SELECT statement would read (as a php statement)

```
$sql=" SELECT $field_list from my_table ";
```

which operates as 
    "SELECT title, first_name,last_name from my_table ";

The problem then arises when trying to display the data from each of these fields. I am trying to use the stucture as follows

```
  $result=mysql_query("$sql");
  while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "the data is $myrow["x"];
  }
```

Howvere, I want to be able to use different values for `x`  which are extracted from the $field_list using substr(). Normaly I would do this by using $x and changing the values as appropriate, but this syntax does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:google]?

Answer (score 0):

Careful with quoting. Try `echo "the data is " . $myrow[$x];` or `echo "the data is {$myrow[$x]}";`